# What exactly are "PHPDoc style comments"?

Tags: php, phpdoc

An evil, nasty bug bit me today. For a long time, I've calculated the number of "pure" rows of PHP source code from PHP scripts. To accomplish this, I looped through all the tokens and removed any instance of T_COMMENT.

In the manual, at https://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php , it says:

```
T_COMMENT   // or #, and /* */  comments
```

It turns out that this did not delete some kind of fancy alternative-style comment, apparently called "PHPDoc style comments". On the same page, further down (which I never looked for, because I had no idea they existed), it says:

```
T_DOC_COMMENT   /** */  PHPDoc style comments
```

Now, my code works, because I account for both kinds.

However, I still wonder what a "PHPDoc style comment" is supposed to be, and why they are not considered part of T_COMMENT.

Frustratingly, the "PHPDoc style comments" hyperlink on that manual page just links to a generic "comments" page which doesn't mention "PHPDoc" anywhere!

So, what is it? Why is it considered a special kind of comment? Why isn't it documented? Why must everything in this life be a complete damn mystery?!

Comment: https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/

Answer (score 0):

These kind of comments are used to read by documentation tools, which analyze your source code and generate documentations about your functions and classes. As an example the [phpDocumentor](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/) is such a tool to generate documentations, similar to [javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc).